# How to manage multiple tfs gated checkin build definitions

Tags: visual-studio-2012

We currently have 2 solutions that share several projects between them, as well as have some projects that are unique to each of them. We currently have a build definition for each of these solutions set to Gated Checkin.

Unfortunately, it seems that having multiple definitions with gated checkins set means that if I make a change to one of the shared projects, it only runs one definition. In a perfect world, I want it to build both solutions in this circumstance.

I know that I could just create a single build definition that builds both solutions, and this will work great in the scenario in question, but then if I am modifying a project that it unique to a solution, it will still build both solutions, ugh.

Is there a way to configure our builds such that we get the best of both worlds? I would like the consistency of insuring shared code correctly works on both solutions, but I also would like builds to not take double the time for changes that affect only one solution or another (by far our most common use case).

Or am I just stuck with the tradeoff of one or the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem with your current situation is "how to identify the change"? Whether it's the common project or the unique project that was modified. I dont think there is any EASY means of identifying this at the time of building the code.

One option which you is NOT THE BEST solution would be to separate out the common projects into another solution which compiles and put the DLL's to a common location which the unique solutions use. This way you can have 3 independent gated- checkins, if there is change to common solution you compile both unique solutions within the same build definition. If not you compile the common and the one unique solution in their own build def.

Comment: Hmm, I agree this should work. It might be the way to go for me, since editing the common projects isn't a hugely common use case, although it would take a fair bit of set up and a new build / deployment strategy for these common projects. Worth looking into for sure if there are no other suggestions forthcoming.

Comment: Sure let me know if you find something better.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well, and it's going to be HARD to separate them out due to how big the code-base is.

Comment: I found that if you make a change that crosses the workspace of multiple gated check-ins then TFS instead of performing both builds, it offers the user a choice of which build to perform, which is clearly no good.